# Descartes Wax Example (second meditation)

Tags: descartes

Descartes provides insightful thinking on the nature of substance using the wax example.

I was wondering if there are any other philosophers who took the wax example and suggested other questions on the nature of substance ? Perhaps objections to Descartes on it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see [Primary/secondary quality distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary/secondary_quality_distinction) and [John Locke and properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/locke/#BooII).

Comment: For the discussion of the "wax argument" into *Meditations*, II, you can see : Edwin Curley, [Descartes Against the Skeptics](https://books.google.it/books?id=iop7qdgDLTUC) (1978), page 210-on. Also : Edwin Curley, [Locke, Boyle, and the Distinction between Primary and Secondary Qualities](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2183887?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1972).